# In Postman API documenter response data not visible

Tags: api, service, postman, postman-collection-runner

I published my postman collection, after published I got documenter Url,from there able to see URL, RequestType, Headers, Body, Data.
But Unable to see Response Data.

Where do we see Response data in postman publish documenter url?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an example in postman after the response is received. then save it. after doing that, you can create the doc  and you'll see your sample responses.